# Short comic book strip from Alan Class reprints of EC type mystery comics about scientist extracting sound from rocks/artefacts

Tags: story-identification, comics

Viewing a recent question regarding ancient voices from stones, I recall a short comic strip with a story of a scientist who extracts historical voices from rocks/artefacts and maybe even projects them visually. Perhaps even the past invaded the present though I am guessing here.

I believe it was in some Alan Class UK reprint of American mystery stories from EC and the like. I must have read it in the 70s and it must have been from the 50s/60s.

Comment: Music with rocks in?